Xerox Primelink C9065 Ubuntu PPD
I'm reaching out to enhance my use of the Xerox Primelink C9065 printer within an Ubuntu setup, managed via CUPS. Despite my efforts, the current PPD limitations prevent full utilization of the printer's capabilities.
A specific challenge is the default backside stapling of documents; my needs require front-side stapling. Additionally, I'm looking to optimize document output by specifying the output bin selection directly.
Could anyone share the necessary PostScript commands or guidance to modify the PPD for:
Front-side stapling or backside printing.
Output bin selection.
Such insights would greatly improve my document handling and printing efficiency.
Thank you for your support :)
I tried to get the information from Xerox but they do not support Linux. There is only a generic PPD for Xerox printers with limited options.
